# Is it possible to pass in WCF client proxy metadata info in request headers?

Tags: wcf, xsd, wsdl

We want some ability to version our client proxies that we generate using a simple YYYY-MM model, or a simple integer, and have server side visibility on this through headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample code on the client:

```
   public class ClientMessageLogger : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        MessageHeader header1 = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Testreply", "http://Test", "Test");
    request.Headers.Add(header1);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("UserAgent", "http://User", "User1");
    reply.Headers.Add(header);
    return null;

    }
}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class CustomBehavior : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public Type TargetContract => typeof(ServiceReference1.ICalculator);
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageLogger());
    }
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Add `[CustomBehavior]` above the interface.

[image]

Here is the reference: [IClientMessageInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem. The headers would need to be populated before the message is sent by the client based on client proxy version. Not after.

Comment: Before the client sends a reply, you can add a custom SOAP message in the BeforeSendReply method.

Comment: Ok, I believe for my situation I would be using IClientMessageInspector. The headers should be added by the client code. Do you know how I can include the message inspector behavior into the svcutil generated client proxies?

Comment: I have tested it and hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I realize my question is a bit ambiguous but your answer is very insightful.